# How to make C++ compile time template cast constant?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time-constant

Is this the only way to initialize default parameter `initial_value` as a compile time constant of type `TNumber`? If not, what is the preferred method of doing so?

```
template <typename TNumber>
class Widget {
 public:
  Widget(TNumber initial_value = static_cast<TNumber>(1))
    : value_(initial_value) {};

 private:
  TNumber value_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is to use a type's expected constructor.  In C++ 98:

```
Widget(TNumber initial_value = TNumber(1));
```

In C++ 11+ you could use the aggregate constructor as well:

```
Widget(TNumber initial_value = TNumber{1});
```

This also works when your parameter is a const ref, as in

```
Widget(const TNumber& initial_value = TNumber{1});
```

By convention, the explicit default constructor returns 0 for numerical values, so the two following lines are equivalent for the standard numerical types (int, char, float, etc...)

```
Widget(const TNumber& initial_value = TNumber{0});

Widget(const TNumber& initial_value = TNumber{});
```

[EDIT] The same is true for complex numbers (std::complex<>).  I suggest you follow the same convention if you ever define your own 'numerical-like' type. It could really save your day at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use default member initialization with template types? So, just ...

private:
    TNumber value_ = 1;